# is libuuid rfc4122 compliant

Tags: c++, uuid

I am currently using uuid_generate_random and uuid_unparse of libuuid to generate uuids. According to the contract requirements of the project that I am working on, uuids generated by our system are supposed to be rfc4122 compliant. Here comes the question: Are "libuuid generated uuids" RFC4122 compliant? If not, what else can be used to generate RFC 4122 compliant uuids under debian OS using c++, I am thinking of: Boost::UUID not quite sure what its situation is when it comes to compliances. If you can share the knowledge, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Implementing [UUID version 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) should be easy enough.

Comment: Thanks, So that's to say libuuid is not RFC 4122 compatible? I don't want to implement something new if I don't need to:)

Comment: AFAICT, it is completely compatible. I'm not posting this as an answer as I mostly just glanced at the code, but it appears to fulfill all the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[boost::uuids::random_generator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/uuid/random_generator.hpp) is RFC 4122 compliant.

I haven't found a reference to RFC 4122 in the libuuid man pages. Probably libuuid is older than the RFC. But the [implementation](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/lib/uuid/gen_uuid.c#n629) looks like it fulfils the requirements.

Comment: To be on the safe side I will use Boost::uuids::random_generator, thank you very much for the response.